# AD FS Password update not working (PasswordValidationError)

Tags: passwords, adfs3.0

If have installed and configured ADFS 3.0 (Windows 2012 R2). Authenticating my webapplication with ADFS is working correctly however when i want to update/change my password i get this error on the ADFS login page:

"The new password is not set. Please contact your system administrator" (translated from dutch)

### In event viewer this error event is logged on the ADFS server (eventID 407):

Password change failed for following user:

Additional Data

User:
@

Server on which password change was attempted:
.domain.local
Error details:

### PasswordValidationError

### ADFS debug tracing comes up with these 2 error events (eventid 53):

PasswordUtil.ChangePassword: directory operation error for user , exception Sytem.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: A value in the request is invalid.

### at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponse(Int32 messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResiltAll resultType, TimeSpan requestTimeOut, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut)

### and

PasswordUtil.ChangePassword: Failed to change password on server with error
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.PasswordManagment.PasswordChangeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.PasswordManagment.PasswordChangeException' was thrown.

### at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.PasswordManagment.PasswordUtil.ChangePassword(String userName, SecureString oldPassword, SecureString new Password)

This fix doesn't need to be installed because the dll's are older then on our ADFS server (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035025)

The endpoint for update passwords in adfs is enabled (ohterwise i didn't get the updatepassword screen).

In the eventviewer of the DC there are informational events which says dat an passwordchange has attempted, which is logged as wel as a password is changed not via ADFS. It seems that the ADFS service account want to change the password which i wanted te change so i made the ADFS service account domain admin but that does not solves the problem and i get the same errors.

On internet didn't find much nor adfs eventid 407 or 53.

Does anyone run into the same issues as i did?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself (with help from Microsoft). The errormessage i go "passwordvalidationerror" is very misleading, i thought it pointed to communication error between AD and ADFS. But the case is that this errormessage is given when your new password is not met with you password policy. We found out that the accounts password policy said "minimum password age" was 21 days. The accounts we tested with had passwords that were not 21 days old yet. So keep in mind that if you want to change your password with ADFS and your new password does not meet your company's password policy the evenviewer message will be "passwordvalidationerror" and check your password policys by typoing the following command in your command prompt: net accounts.